# Magento-2.4.2 Cart View Throwing Errors

Tags: magento2

We just managed to upgrade Magento Open Source from Version-2.2.1 to 2.2.4 and the upgrade went pretty well after multiple attempts. Now we are stuck with one problem, we can add items to the carts and are able to successfully checkout. But the problem comes when we try to view the cart, it will throw the following error's. Anybody faced the same issue ??

Platform:

O.S: Ubuntu-20.04

Php-7.4

Mariadb-10.4

Apache-2.4

Please find the error Screenshot below

==============================================================
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Sm/styleshop/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml on line 12

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Sm/styleshop/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml on line 12

```
#1 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:71]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:273]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:303]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1111]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1115]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:675]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [app/design/frontend/Sm/styleshop/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/default.phtml:63]
#8 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:71]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:273]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:303]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1111]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1115]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:675]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/AbstractCart.php:134]
#15 Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart->getItemHtml() called at [app/design/frontend/Sm/styleshop/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml:39]
#16 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:71]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:273]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:303]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1111]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1115]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:675]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:578]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:555]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:522]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml:16]
#39 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:71]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:273]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:303]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1111]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1115]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:675]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:578]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:555]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#67 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#69 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#71 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#75 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#76 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#77 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#78 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#79 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#80 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#81 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#82 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#83 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#84 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#85 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#86 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#87 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#88 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#89 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#90 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#91 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#92 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:149]
#93 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#94 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:140]
#95 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:975]
#96 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#97 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#98 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#99 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:347]
#100 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#101 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#102 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#103 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#104 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#105 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:95]
#106 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#107 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#108 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#109 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:29]
```

==============================================================

Comment: You should not post code or log files as images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

The error is due to an override being done in that phtml file which looks like to be from the Styleshop theme (which I've never used), you should include what's in that file. Also, did you upgrade to 2.2.4 or 2.4.2? Double-check what's the compatibility list reported by your theme provider.

Comment: Thank you. I've corrected the main thread by replacing the image with Text. Also, we had upgraded it from 2.2.1 to 2.4.2. We are checking the issue with Styleshop Theme now. Thanks again.